# copy integer to a pointer structure variable

Tags: c, pointers, structure

I'm trying to assign a value to a pointer structure variable. 
This is what I'm trying to do -

```
struct node
    {
        char name[31];
        int probability[3];
        struct node *ptr;
    };
    typedef struct node NODE;

NODE *head;

   head  = (NODE *)malloc(sizeof(NODE));
   head->probability[0] = atoi(strtok (buf," -"));//Doesn't assingn
   head->probability[1] = atoi(strtok(NULL," -"));//Doesn't assingn
   head->probability[2] = atoi(strtok(NULL," -"));//Doesn't assingn
```

Here "buf" is a string that contains values in "5 10 0" format. But the above code is not assigning value to head->probability . 
Please give me a solution.

Comment: that should work. Can you provide a [mcve] ,

Comment: how `buf` is declared?

Comment: Put in diagnostic printfs to check the returns from strtok.

Comment: I have already checked them. Problem solved. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 2):

It works fine for me. Here is my code

```
// FILE: test_struct.c

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>

#define NAME_LEN 31
#define PROB_LEN 3

struct node {
    char name[NAME_LEN];
    int probability[PROB_LEN];
    struct node *ptr;
};

typedef struct node NODE;

int main() 
{
   char buf[] = "5 10 0";
   NODE *head;
   int i;

   head = (NODE *)malloc(sizeof(NODE));
   assert(head);

   // add probabilities
   for (i=0; i < PROB_LEN; i++)
       head->probability[i] = atoi(strtok ((i == 0) ? buf : NULL," -"));

   // print probabilities
   for (i = 0; i < PROB_LEN; i++)
       printf("head->probability[%d] = %d\n", i, head->probability[i]);

   free(head);
   return 0;
}
```

Compilation and execution

```
gcc test_struct.c -o ts
./ts
```

Print Results

```
head->probability[0] = 5
head->probability[1] = 10
head->probability[2] = 0
```

Comment: It's my pleasure to have helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the main problem is that `strtok` performs in-place replacement of delimiter with `\0` symbol:

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strtok.html

> it is overwritten by a null byte, which terminates the current token

if you declare buf variable as `char * buf = "5 10 0";` it means that buf points to read only data section, so strtok cannot be used, easy solution to fix is to use `char buf[] = "5 10 0";`

Comment: I declared the buf as char buf[100]. Still had the problem. However the problem is solved. Thanks anyways.